# how to assign id to tag , bootstrap tags input, asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to add and remove and show tags from database using bootstrap tags input
for example
tag1
tag2
tag3

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

I need to pass id of tag to action method instead of tagtitle
so I set value of option like this

```
<option value="@item.Id">
```

the problem is tagiputs shows 1 , 2 , 3 instead of tag1,tag2,tag3
I mean it shows Id's instead of tag titles

**so the quesion is how can I assign both id and text to tags?
and pass Id and text of tags to action?**

this is html

```
        <select multiple data-role="tagsinput" id="testtaginput">
            @{
            foreach (var item in data.TagDataList)
            {
            <option value="@item.Id">@item.TagTitle</option>
            }
            }
        </select>
```

and this is javascript

```
<script>
$('#testtaginput').on('itemAdded', function (event) {
    debugger;

    var item = event.item;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/AddTag?tagtitle=' + item,

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

            },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
    });

});

$('#testtaginput').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {



    var item = event.item;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/DeleteTag?tagtitle=' + item,

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
 <option value="@item.Id#@item.TagName">
```

Then
Split it with '#'

Before sending the request, you should create json object which include Id, TagName such as

```
{
 "Id" : 1,
 "TagName" : "test"
}
```

You should pass the object to method.